# how to create a simple tab menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My tab works well if I have a lot of text.
[image]

But has soon as I shrink the text the tab get's smaller. Any idea what settings may be causing this?

***I know it works well with only bootstrap. I think I have a settings that is messing up my tab. What should I be looking for in my custom css? This is my css: https://ufile.io/ve4xc***

[image]

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills brand-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav active"><a href="#app" aria-controls="app" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Application</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav"><a href="#gitlab" aria-controls="gitlab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">GitLab</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="brand-nav"><a href="#docker" aria-controls="docker" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Docker</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="app">
                                    <p>
                                        Lo
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="gitlab">
                                
                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="docker">
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsizzle dolor away amizzle, consectetuer pizzle elizzle. Nullizzle yo velizzle, check it out volutpizzle, quis, gravida vel, yo.
                                        Ma nizzle eget tortor. Sizzle eros. My shizz izzle dolizzle gizzle turpis tempizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle.
                                        Maurizzle pellentesque nibh izzle own yo'. Check it out in tortor. Pellentesque fizzle rhoncizzle nisi.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Shizzlin dizzle dapibus. You son of a bizzle tellizzle urna, pretizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle,
                                        ghetto ac, check it out vitae, nunc. Shizzlin dizzle suscipizzle. Integizzle sempizzle velit sizzle dizzle.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                                    <p>
                                        Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks.
                                        Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without
                                        revolutionary ROI.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value.
                                        Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar
                                        solutions without functional solutions.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate
                                        one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service
                                        for state of the art customer service.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: try to understand grid layout in bootstrap, you're missing some elements

Comment: it works without my custom css. so it's my css. everything works well without it but i dont know which setting is causing this. Check this: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3kerp

Comment: are you expecting us to download your CSS? Just post it here

Comment: how can I post a 10000 lines of code here?? Says exceeded caracters..

Comment: please make a plnk and share the link : https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Well, my guess is that you need to set the class "row" to the first div:

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                         ...
```

Try that. I also recommend you to check bootstrap grid documentation to get it right.

Comment: didn't help. Dude it's not the bootstrap. It's my css theme. without my css it works.